# Ros Bridge Publishing cmd_vel from move_base

Tags: ros, ros2, rosbridge

I am working on a project which requires slam and autonomous navigation. When in Noetic I have created a map and will use move base because the lidar has plenty of drivers for ROS and not ROS2 so I’m thinking of doing all the mapping etc in Noetic and then physically driving the robot in ROS2 because I need to use ROS2 as part of the project. I have read of issues with publishing ROS1 cmd_vel message to ROS 2 because of the “different” message types. Is there any way around this. Or is it possible to publish the map topic over the bridge